# PIL: How to get the full range of a color with ImageGrab

Tags: python

I want to get the full range of a color stored in a variable.

Using `ImageGrab`, how can I get the whole color range of a specific color, rather than writing each shade one-by-one?

```
while True:
    rgb = PIL.ImageGrab.grab().load()[960,540]
    if rgb == (1, 0, 0) or rgb == (2, 0, 0) or rgb == (3, 0, 0):
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You seem to maybe be a little unclear as to how RGB works. Try checking `rgb(255,1,3)` in an online colour checker.

Comment: lets say i have the color red then i want all the rgb values from the upper range to the lower range of red stored in one variable

Comment: There is no *"range of red"*, it's subjective. `rgb(255,5,12)` will look very red. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Is this along the lines of what you're after ([matplotlib colour scales](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html))?  For example, if you want the 'red' colourscale, call the `Reds` colour map.  You might need to create a mapping from your `if` statement to the appropriate colourmap - but the maps are built into `matplotlib`.